# merge local repository to remote repository

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I have got a requirement to copy my local repository to remote repository which is private in github.

Right now i have my code base in my own gitlab server, Client asked me to merge my code to his repository by adding his repository as remote to my gitlab repo. I'm not sure how to achieve this. I could able to follow below steps but unable to push my code.

```
 cd my-code
 git remote add client 
 git push origin client
 error: src refspec ben does not match any.
 error: failed to push some refs to
```

Am i doing it in wrong way? Can someone guide me to do it in write way?

Comment: Now I need to ask, this repository was created from scratch, o was cloned from client repository ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern for the push command is like following:

```
git push <remotename> <branchname>
```

So if you added the repository from the client with the remote name client (which you did by executing "git remote add client"), your push command should look like this:

```
git push client <branchname>
```

For < branchname > you should insert the branch you want to push (probably your feature or development branch).

Answer (score 2):

Both histories are not related, so, basic git commands can't help you this time

For example you repo has this history (this is a simplificated version only to show the concept):

A - B - C <-- master

And the repo where you are trying to push (client) has this:

S - T - U - V - X - Y - Z <-- master

If you try to do a git push of your repo to client it would be rejected because Z is not ancestor of C, even, Z is NOT related to C in anyway

If you do a force push (**DON'T DO THAT**), you will overwrite all the information of your client repo,  so, **DON'T DO THAT**

If you dont mind losing all your history, you can copy your files to a local clone of client repository, and do only one commit "Added all my files to repo", but if you need to keep your history on client repo for some reason, this is what I would do:

Rebase all your changes on client/master branch, but before that, you need to check if is ok for your client repo to merge your directory structure into theirs, or if you need to push your code to a subdirectory (first case, jump to step 1, second case continue to step 0)

**Step 0) Move your files to a subdirectory**

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'mkdir anothernewdir; mv *.* anothernewdir/'
```

NOTE: if you need to undo the filter-branch operation, you can do it with git reset:

```
git reset --hard master@{1}
```

**Step 1) Rebase your client branch**

```
git rebase client/master
```

**Step 2) Push your changes (NO force push required) with -u flag (to track upstream)**

```
git push -u client master:refs/heads/master
```

Comment: How do you now, that the histories are not related?

Comment: It seems like the asker is trying to merge a local repository he started from scratch

Answer (score -3):

A `git pull client` before the push should solve

Comment: You can't push without telling git *what* to push. Git doesn't know anything about which branches you want to sync on your local repo with the newly added remote.